# Oracle subqueries with join

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

**Explaining the scenario:**

I have a real state system for units renting build on oracle database. Where  in my system I have a list of groups buildings , list of buildings and each building has its units.

on each building there are multiple units that their prices differ baseed on its location and number of rooms, kitchen, bathroom, balcony and car parking ... etc

**for example:**

- street view units with 3 bedrooms ($15K / yearly)
- back side view units with 3 bedrooms ($13K / yearly)
- corner street view and side view units with 4 bedrooms ($18K / yearly)
- corner street view and side view units with 4 bedrooms ($18K / yearly)
- and so on ...

some units are rented and some units is not rented

I am looking to get the list of units based on its specifications and prices list.

I have coded a query to give me the list like this:

```
SELECT GR.G_NO, MIN(U.ANNUAL_RENT),MIN(U.U_NO), MIN(U.U_CODE), MIN(UT.UNIT_TYPE),  U.VARAND_NAME, U.UNIT_STATE, COUNT(U.UNIT_STATE) , COUNT(UT.UNIT_TYPE), min(U.COUNT_ROOM), min(U.PATH_NO), min(U.GALARY_NO), 
FROM UNITS U 
JOIN UNIT_TYPE UT
ON UT.UNIT_NO = U.UNIT_NO
JOIN GROUPS GR
ON GR.G_NO = U.G_NO
JOIN BUILDS B
ON B.B_NO = U.B_NO
WHERE 
GR.G_NO = B.G_NO
GROUP BY GR.G_NO, B.B_NAME, U.VARAND_NAME, U.UNIT_STATE, U.ANNUAL_RENT
ORDER BY GR.G_NO, B.B_NAME, MIN(U.ANNUAL_RENT),MIN(U.U_NO)
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Where the output is like this:

[image]

if you look at record 3 and 4 are the they have the same specification and the same prices, Where The only different is UNIT_STATE and COUNT(U.UNIT_STATE)
(y) rented (1 unit) or (N) not rented (2 units)

what I am looking for is to get the count of units by COUNT(U.UNIT_STATE) on separate columns like this

[image]

where I get :

- The total number of **units** by the same type and specifications ,
- The total number of **Rented** units by the same type and specifications ,
- The total number of **Not Rented** units by the same type and specifications ,

so for example the record number 3 the total units are 3  where 1 unit is rented and 2 units are not rented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you need something like this (not tested due to lack of test data):

```
SELECT GR.G_NO, 
       MIN(U.ANNUAL_RENT) ,
       MIN(U.U_NO), 
       MIN(U.U_CODE), 
       MIN(UT.UNIT_TYPE),  
       U.VARAND_NAME, 
       COUNT(U.UNIT_STATE) as total_unit_by_same_type,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN UNIT_STATE = 'Y' THEN 1 END ) as "COUNT(U.UNIT_STATE)=Y",
       COUNT( CASE WHEN UNIT_STATE = 'N' THEN 1 END ) as "COUNT(U.UNIT_STATE)=N",
       COUNT(UT.UNIT_TYPE), 
       min(U.COUNT_ROOM), 
       min(U.PATH_NO), 
       min(U.GALARY_NO),
       U.ANNUAL_RENT
FROM .... 
...... rest of your query goes here
.....
.....
GROUP BY GR.G_NO, 
      B.B_NAME, 
      U.VARAND_NAME,
      U.ANNUAL_RENT
ORDER BY GR.G_NO, B.B_NAME, MIN(U.ANNUAL_RENT),MIN(U.U_NO)
```